# using all() to compare two dataframe columns with lists of strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe with two columns with lists of strings, and I need to know if all elements of a list are contained in the other list.

Initially my values were strings, here's an example:

```
df1
       num
0     [10 2]
1     [120]
2     [2 5 8]
```

```
df2
       num
0     [10 2]
1     [60]
2     [2 5]
```

Then I used `df1['num'].str.split()` to get the elements in the string into a list:

```
df1
       num
0     [10, 2]
1     [120]
2     [2, 5, 8]
```

After that I tried using `all(item in df1['num'].str.split() for item in df2['num'].str.split())`
but it outputs:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

The desirable output would be:

```
0     True
1     False
2     True
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'num': [['10', '2'], ['120'], ['2', '5', '8']]
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'num': [['10', '2'], ['60'], ['2', '5']]
})

df1_str = pd.DataFrame(df1['num'].str)
df2_str = pd.DataFrame(df2['num'].str)

lst = [all(df2_str[col].isin(df1_str[col])) for col in df2_str.columns]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `issubset` method with convert values from `df1['num']` to `set`s:

```
df1['new'] = [set(b).issubset(a) for a,b in zip(df1['num'], df2['num'])]
print (df1)
         num    new
0    [10, 2]   True
1      [120]  False
2  [2, 5, 8]   True
```

If values are not splitted modify solution by:

```
df1['test'] = [set(b.split()).issubset(a.split()) for a,b in zip(df1['num'], df2['num'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set operations here:

```
pd.Series([set(a)>=set(b) for a,b in zip(df1['num'], df2['num'])], index=df1.index)
```

output:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Or to assign to one of the dataframes:

```
df1['test'] = [set(a)>=set(b) for a,b in zip(df1['num'], df2['num'])]
```

output:

```
         num   test
0    [10, 2]   True
1      [120]  False
2  [2, 5, 8]   True
```